# run blocking and launch are running in main thread, performing an operation of for loop more than 5 seconds. It's not causing ANR Error?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-anr-dialog

when we perform an operation on the main thread for more than 5 seconds, it will throw an ANR Error. But here,
runblocking and launch are running in the main thread, but it's not throwing ANR Error.

My code snippet:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_coroutine) 
Log.d("test", "Main program started ${Thread.currentThread().name}")                           
runBlocking { Log.d("test", "run blocking ${Thread.currentThread().name}")

     var job =  launch {
            Log.d("test", "launch: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
          for(i in 1..500){
              println("$i...")
              Thread.sleep(50)
          }
        }

        job.join()
        Log.d("test","Main program ended ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
    Log.d("test","activity oncreate() ended ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
} 
}
```

I can see the o/p as follows:

Main program started the main

run blocking the main

launch: main
1..
2..
.
.
500

Main program ended

Mainactivity oncreate() ended main

If we perform an operation in Main thread more than 5 seconds, it must throw ANR Error.

Comment: 5 seconds is a rough minimum. It can be more depending on device and other conditions. I've seen it take about 15 seconds before. Anything more than 17ms is already enough to cause UI jank, so we don't really need to worry about when the ANR will arrive because that's long after the amount of acceptable time.

Comment: But generally you are correct - this code should block the UI thread and make the application freeze.